# Is there a way to get more than 1 value using?

Tags: sqlite, better-sqlite3

I have a `better-sqlite3` statement that orders and ranks my database, and I have a `IN` statement so I can select more than 1 row. That is where I run into an issue, I need to fetch multiple rows based on a dynamic array of IDs.

My SQLITE Statement looks like this:

```sql
Table.prepare('SELECT *, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC) rank FROM table WHERE user IN(?)');
```

And I try to get from this statement with things like this:

```js
getAll.get(['1','2','3']);
getAll.get('6,9,4');
getAll.get('7','5','8');
```

I get an error:

```
RangeError: Too many parameter values were provided
```

How exactly can I select multiple values without knowing the length of my array (so `?,?` won't cut it), and allow as much values as possible? I used `?*` and I get a Syntax error.

I am using `better-sqlite3` for `Node.JS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `IN` use the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC) rank 
FROM table 
WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || user || ',%'
```

and pass the list as 1 string of comma separated values (without spaces):

```
all('6,9,4');
```

Comment: This only returns the first result I think? I'm using `better-sqlite3` and I didn't get anything like an Array, I just got a single row.

Comment: This query returns all the rows where user is 6 or 9 or 4 if you pass the string '6,9,4'. For the better-sqlite3 code I'm not sure, I used your code of getAll() which is the only appropriate for this case because it passes just 1 string.

Comment: @SomePerson from the documentation of `all()`: *Similar to .get(), but instead of only retrieving one row all matching rows will be retrieved. The return value is an array of row objects.* So use `all()` instead of `get()`.